# Creating extension methods for SeqLike

Tags: scala, collections, implicit-conversion

Let's say I want to extend the functionality of `SeqLike`:

```
import collection.SeqLike

implicit class Test[A, Repr <: SeqLike[A, Repr]](val sq: Repr) extends AnyVal {
  def foo(): Repr = sq
}
```

Then this doesn't work:

```
Vector(1, 2, 3).foo()
```

Also not:

```
new Test(Vector(1, 2, 3)).foo()

<console>:41: error: inferred type arguments
                    [Nothing,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] 
                    do not conform to class Test's type parameter bounds 
                    [A,Repr <: scala.collection.SeqLike[A,Repr]]
              new Test(Vector(1, 2, 3)).foo()
              ^
```

Only this works:

```
new Test[Int, Vector[Int]](Vector(1, 2, 3)).foo()
```

How can I make the implicit class work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have `sq` be typed as a `SeqLike` instead of a type parameter. This will allow the compiler to have some firm ground on which to rely, from which `Repr` can then be inferred.
The only apparent problem now would be that we're going to have a type mismatch  in `foo`, as it is supposed to return a `Repr` but we return a `SeqLike[A, Repr]`.

The solution is simple enough, use the `repr` method:

```
implicit class Test[A, Repr](val sq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def foo(): Repr = sq.repr
}
Vector(1, 2, 3).foo()
```

Comment: Ok, of course. The problem is that for some methods I need `CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, ...]` which will not apply to `sq` any more. But otherwise this works.

Comment: Fair enough. In this case, just post another question describing the actual problem involving `CanBuildFrom`, we'll see if we can find a solution. EDIT: oh, you've just done exactly that, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually solve this like this:

```
implicit class Test[A, Repr <: SeqLike[A, Repr]](val sq: Repr with SeqLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
```

However, this won't work properly with `Array` or `String`, so `IsTraversableLike` is a better solution. If you truly need `SeqLike`, it's very easy to duplicate `IsTraversableLike`.