# Collection extension method which preserved both element type A and representation type Repr

Tags: scala, collections, implicit-conversion

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426411/creating-extension-methods-for-seqlike/20427464), can I devise *one* implicit class that handles two types of `SeqLike` extensions:

```
import collection.SeqLike
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class Test[A, Repr](val sq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  // no constraints on Repr
  def foo[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr = sq.sortBy(f)

  // constraint that actually sq is Repr
  def bar[B, To](fun: (A, A) => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, To]): To = {
    val b = cbf(sq)  // NO!
    // ...
    b.result
  }
}
```

The `bar` method doesn't compile because we are missing the constraint that `typeOf(sq) == Repr`. As others have pointed out, if I change the constructor to `sq: Repr`, we lose the connection to type `A`.

Right now, `Repr` is disconnected. For example:

```
// in Test:
def isSortedBy[B](fun: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Boolean =
  sq.sliding(2, 1).forall {
    case a +: b +: _  => ord.lteq(fun(a), fun(b))
    case _            => true  // happens when it size == 1
  }

[error] Test.scala: inferred type arguments [T,Equals] do not conform to method 
                    unapply's type parameter bounds 
                    [T,Coll <: scala.collection.SeqLike[T,Coll]]
[error]         case a +: b +: _  => ord.lteq(fun(a), fun(b))
[error]                ^
```

Comment: I think `self.sliding` should be `sq.sliding` right?

Comment: @stew - yes, sorry that was a mistake from copy+paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, as in your other question, use `repr` and change the type of `sq` to `SeqLike` instead of `Repr`.
But unlike in my previous solution, you can keep the upper type bound to `Repr` (`Repr<:SeqLike[A,Repr]`) to adress the remaining typing problems.
By example:

```
implicit class Test[A, Repr<:SeqLike[A,Repr]](val sq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  // no constraints on Repr
  def foo[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr = sq.sortBy(f)

  // constraint that actually sq is Repr
  def bar[B, To](fun: (A, A) => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, To]): To = {
    val b = cbf(sq.repr)  // NO!
    var x = sq.head
    sq.tail.foreach { y =>
      b+=fun(x,y)  
      x = y
    }
    b.result
  }
  def isSortedBy[B](fun: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Boolean =
    sq.sliding(2, 1).forall {
      case a +: b +: _  => ord.lteq(fun(a), fun(b))
      case _            => true  // happens when it size == 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand the problem correctly,

- if you set the class parameter `sq` to be a `Repr`, you lose the type `A` (there is nothing to infer it from anymore),
- but if you set it to be a `SeqLike[A, Repr]`, then you lose the fact that is also is a `Repr`, so `cbf(sq)` doesn't compile anymore.

Then what about doing both:

```
implicit class Test[A, Repr](val sq: Repr with SeqLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
   ...
}
```

This version compiles fine and I can call `foo` and `bar` on a simple `List(1,2,3)`.

**Edit**: if you want to manipulate values of type `Repr` other than `sq` as collections, you also need the type bound `Repr <: SeqLike[A,Repr]` from Régis's answer.

The only thing `sq: Repr with SeqLike[A, Repr]` gives you is that you can use `sq` instead of `sq.repr` everywhere, since it is already properly typed.